# How to populate a select tag from values based on another select tag with codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

Please forgive me if I make any mistakes in english, its not really my best language. I will edit this post if I make errors please let me know.

I'm trying to make a php page with Codeigniter with a select tag whose values are from a database, and am trying to populate a second select tag based from the value placed on the former.

My college_subj database have three columns.
CollCode, SC, and Subj.

Basically, the College Code(CollCode) and Subject Code(SC) have combinations. A College Code X can have A,B,C SC, and College Code Y can have B,C,D,E SC. I am trying to make those SC appear on my second select tag when the first select tag, the CollCode, has a value.

The page's function is accept values from the two select tags and insert it into the database.

Here's the select tags on my edit.php:

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();>index.php/Controller/insertfunction" id="crq">    
        <h3>Select College Code:</h3>
        <select id="codecrq" name="code">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---Select College Code---</option>
            <?php foreach ($code as $row4): ?>
            <option label="<?php echo $row4['Code']; ?>"   value="<?php echo $row4['Code']; ?>" <?php echo set_select('code', $row4['Code'], False); ?>> <?php echo $row4['Code'] ; ?> </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        
        <h3>Select SC:</h3>
        <select id="sccrq" name="sc">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---Select SC---</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

Here's how I get the values that I placed in the Code select tag which is in the Model:

```
public function Code() {  
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('college_subj.CollCode');
    $this->db->from('college_subj');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Here's a jquery that I try to use to populate the SC select tag:

```js
$("#codecrq").change(function(){
        var selectedMark = $("code").val();
            if(selectedMark !== ""){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "Controller/sccrq/" + selectedMark,
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#sccrq").html("");
                        $("#sccrq").append("<option value=''></option>");
                        $.each(data, function(){
                            $("#sccrq").append("<option value='" + this.sc + "'>" + this.sc + "</option>");
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

and here's the sccrq code from my controller, which is supposed to get the SCs based from the College Code combination and pass it on the SC select tag:

```
function sccrq($code){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('college_subj.sc');
    $this->db->from('college_subj');
    $this->db->where($code);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $query;
}
```

I try making it run, but nothing comes out from the SC select tag.

Any help will be deeply appreciated!
Thank you for you're time!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
function sccrq($code){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SC FROM college_subj WHERE code = '".$code."'");
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that!
But an error Controller/sccrq/undefined 404 (Not Found) came up on my console :o

Comment: url: "Controller/sccrq/" + selectedMark, i think that you called wrong Controller/sccrq you shouldn't call direct file. Ex: url/FunctionNameFromControllerFile + add this function name in routes.php if your function isn't index

Comment: I've edited the routes a bit and the 404 error is finally gone from the console. But no data is getting passed to the Select tag yet

Comment: Where did you put this code ? `function sccrq($code){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('college_subj.sc');
    $this->db->from('college_subj');
    $this->db->where($code);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $query;
}` ? in models or in controllers ?

Comment: I placed it in the Controller

Comment: CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete) should be placed in models and returned result shoud be feteched by Controller

Comment: Oh God thanks for reminding me hahahaha. After a few days of tinkering I've finally managed to do it. Thanks for your time and your replies :DD